# Sorting lists in python issue

Tags: python, list, sorting

I started learning python few days ago (with no prior programming experience nor knowledge) and am currently stuck with the following thing I do not understand:
Let' say I have an unsorted list "b" and I want to sort a list "c" which looks exactly like list "b":

```
b = [4,3,1,2]
c=b
c.sort()

print b
print c
```

What I discovered is that both b and c are sorted:
[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3,4]

Why is that so?

It seems this solution works perfectly when I create a copy of the "b" list:

```
b = [4,3,1,2]
c=b[:]
c.sort()

print b
print c
```

Results in:
[4,3,1,2]
[1,2,3,4]

But why does the first solution not work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first sample, you are copying `b` into `c` by reference, which means that whenever any change (sorting, for example) is made on `b`, it will be applied on `c`, because basically they both point to the same object.

In the second sample, you are copying the array `by value`, not `by reference`, which create an entirely new object in the memory. Therefore, any changes made on the one of them will not be applied on the other one.

Comment: Thank you Kocko.
Does that mean that whenever I need to copy some variable, I should never use the copying by reference as it might cause problems like these?

Comment: Depends on what you need. :)

Comment: Could you elaborate this a bit more?
I what case copy by reference could be useful?

Comment: For instance in the cases when you want to pass an object to a method, you're passing the object by reference, not by value, and if the method modifies the object internally, this modification will be visible outside the method.

Comment: I already understood(on the basic level) most of things but not classes. So if that "object" you mentioned is related with classes, I will have to get back to this once I understand the classes.
Thank you anyhow.

Answer (score 4):

You already seem to understand that `c = b` is different to `c = b[:]`. In the first case `c` references the same object as `b`. In the latter it references a copy of `b`.

So it shouldn't be surprising that since `b.sort()` sorts the list referenced by `b`, When you inspect `c` it is also sorted - because it's the *same object*

The usual way to decouple a sorted list from the original is

```
c = sorted(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because in the first solution, `b` and `c` both point to the same object. The slicing in the second solution creates a new object with the same contents as the old.

Comment: @squiguy: Reference copy. "Shallow" here has a different implication.